# Applications installations location

Tags: software-installation

I am installing many applications -both from terminal line ubuntu software centre. But I am unable to find out where those files are getting saved.Pls help me out

Comment: In the folder `/usr/share/applications/` you can find all the `.desktop` files those are just the applications icons,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xfce4-appfinder](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xfce4-appfinder/) or [Beagle](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beagle).

Below is an explanation of the Linux directory structure, and what everyone is used for.  Hope that it helps.

> In the Linux operating system, all filesystems are contained within
>   one directory hierarchy. The root directory is the top level
>   directory, and all its subdirectories make up the directory hierarchy.
>   This differs to other operating systems such as MS-Windows which
>   applies a separate hierarchy for each device and partition.
>
> /bin -- binary applications (most of your executable files)
>
> /boot -- files required to boot (such as the kernel, etc)
>
> /dev -- your devices (everything from drives to displays)
>
> /etc -- just about every configuration file for your system
>
> /etc/profile.d -- contains scripts that are run by /etc/profile upon
>   login.
>
> /etc/rc.d -- contains a number of shell scripts that are run on bootup
>   at different run levels. There is also typically an rc.inet1 script to
>   set up networking (in Slackwar), an rc.modules script to load modular
>   device drivers, and an rc.local script that can be edited to run
>   commands desired by the administrator, along the lines of autoexec.bat
>   in DOS.
>
> /etc/rc.d/init.d -- contains most of the initialization scripts
>   themselves on an rpm-based system.
>
> /etc/rc.d/rc*.d -- where "*" is a number corresponding to the default
>   run level. Contains files for services to be started and stopped at
>   that run level. On rpm-based systems, these files are symbolic links
>   to the initialization scripts themselves, which are in
>   /etc/rc.d/init.d.
>
> /etc/skel -- directory containing several example or skeleton
>   initialization shells. Often contains subdirectories and files used to
>   populate a new user's home directory.
>
> /etc/X11 -- configuration files for the X Window system
>
> /home -- locally stored user files and folders
>
> /lib -- system libraries (similar to Program Files)
>
> /lost+found -- lost and found for lost files
>
> /media -- mounted (or loaded) devices such as cdroms, digital cameras,
>   etc.
>
> /mnt -- mounted file systems
>
> /opt -- location for “optionally” installed programs
>
> /proc -- dynamic directory including information about and listing of
>   processes
>
> /root -- “home” folder for the root user
>
> /sbin -- system-only binaries (see /bin)
>
> /sys -- contains information about the system
>
> /tmp -- temporary files
>
> /usr -- applications mainly for regular users
>
> /var -- mainly logs, databases, etc.
>
> /usr/local/bin -- the place to put your own programs. They will not be
>   overwritten with upgrades.
>
> /usr/share/doc -- documentation.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Linux or Ubuntu Directory structure](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/linux-or-ubuntu-directory-structure.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of files installed by a package by using:

```
dpkg -L <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install the browser chromium for example with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. You can see the installed files from the chromium-browser package with `dpkg -L chromium-browser`.

**See:** [Linux or ubuntu Directory structure](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/linux-or-ubuntu-directory-structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in terminal:

```
whereis NAME
```

For example:

```
whereis firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

And finally, another possibility is Synaptic. Once a package is installed, you can click on the "installed Files" tab (in the list of tabs that contain package description etc.)